# Static Navbar - collapse on small device - logo should hide - Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, affix

Hey So i have a static Navigation that will collapse when the browser size is getting smaller. (Bootstrap 3 navigation)

Now i have a logo inside there as well. I want the collapsed navigation to scroll down with the user, that's working. I'm using affix for it. 
But i want to hide the Logo now. Like the logo should be fixed while the collapsed navigation is scrolling. 
The only thing i figured out is to let the logo fade out after scrolling down some px. 
Anyone got an idea?? here's the HTML code:

```
<div id="nav">
        <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static" role="navigation">
            <div class="second-nav">
                <!-- .btn-navbar is used as the toggle for collapsed navbar content -->
                <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>

                <div class="nav-logo">
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/Logo_nav.png" alt="DnD"></a>
                </div>


                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="mainnav nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#archievements">Leistungen</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#about">Über uns</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#team">Team</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#actuell" class="dropdown-toggle disabled" data-toggle="dropdown">Aktuelles<b class="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#actuellall">Alle Artikel</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#customers">Kunden</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#jobs" class="dropdown-toggle disabled" data-toggle="dropdown">Jobs<b class="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#jobsall">Alle Jobs</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#contact">Kontakt</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what the problem is you are having. Could you make a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or a [Bootply](http://bootply.com) with your current code in that shows what is happening currently, and explain how this differs from what you expect.

Comment: Here's the bootply 
http://www.bootply.com/mS20RaDgaG
As you can see i have a navigation with the words home leistungen etc. Besides there is the DnD. As soon as the navigation collapse (browser window gets smaller, mobile device) and the user scrolls down, i want the navigation to follow the scroll down but the DnD should stay at the top. so DnD at the top -> not visibile as soon as i scroll down, navigation -> scroll down. 
Hope you understand !